# How to access the iphone folder system in C# winforms application

Tags: c#, iphone, file, file-io, directory-structure

I am trying to create a winforms application using C#, I want the user to be able to select a folder on an iPhone device that is connected via USB and it copies images to a new folder selected by a user, sorting them in folders by date, month and year. At the moment I have just started out, I have got my application selecting folders, however this is only on the PC directories, my iPhone doesn't show up under /This PC when running the program.

As shown
[image: Code at the moment]

When the USB device (my iPhone 11 latest iOS as of 30.07.23) is plugged in this is all that is shown:[image]

Even though in file explorer it shows up as a device.